# Click on macro name to jump to its definition?

Tags: emacs, editors, auctex, aquamacs, texdef

Encouraged by a super response to [my previous question on a similar topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113376/click-on-package-name-to-open-corresponding-style-file), I shall persevere with a similar line of inquiry. I think it would be super if, in my LaTeX editor, I could click on a macro name:

```
\blob{4}
```

and the cursor would jump to the corresponding definition:

```
\newcommand{\blob}[1]{...}
```

Do any LaTeX editors have this feature? I mainly use Aquamacs/AucTeX myself, but am interested in other editors too. I reckon it would be quite challenging to implement, because `\blob` might not just be defined in the current document - it might be:

- in a master file that includes the current document,
- in a slave file that the current document includes, or
- in a package that the document uses.

Comment: ... or defined in the latex format ... or be a tex primitive. depends how much you want to thrash your disk. Recently to answer a less than complete question on this site we had to do find . -name \*.sty -exec grep zzzz \{\}\; to search every file in the input tree for a command to find out where it came from. You probably don't want to hide that behind a single keystroke.

Comment: What is easier of course is to _show_ the definition as that just means executing `\show\blob`

Comment: Ooh that sounds like a good way to go. Maybe somebody could construct an emacs macro that, when you click on the command `\blob`, writes the result of `\show\blob` to a buffer or a tooltip?

Comment: You could collect all the package names and then execute something like this in the shell  `texdef -t latex -p longtable -p tabularx longtable`  which returns the definition, texdef has options to return instead the filename at which the definition was found (it has lots of options:-)

Comment: Just yesterday I examined `\bar` as redefined by `amsmath`; would you believe me when I say that the redefinition by `amsmath` is performed by `\@tempa{\bar}`? Really, apart from *very* simple cases, this is impossible.

Comment: I understand that it's impossible to jump to definitions with *complete* generality. Still, I believe it would be possible to make something that's *useful*, by just concentrating on the common cases. (And you could still resort to `\show`ing definitions in those cases where jumping is not practical, right?)

Comment: This feature would be awesome.

Answer (score 20):

The general problem of finding *where* a command is defined has no viable solution. Macros can and *do* change their meaning; a typical example is `\\`. This simple document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\show\\

{\centering\show\\}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\show\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

gives the following output in the terminal window:

```
> \\=macro:
->\x@protect \\\protect \\  .
l.4 \show\\

?
> \\=macro:
->\ifhmode \unskip \else \@nolnerr \fi \par \@ifstar {\nobreak \@xcentercr }\@xcentercr .
l.6 {\centering\show\\
                      }
?
> \\=macro:
->{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifstar \@xtabularcr \@xtabularcr .
l.9 \show\\
```

Thus, besides caching your entire preamble, a safe routine should also compile your document in order to get the *actual* meaning of a macro.

Another example. Suppose you load `siunitx` and do `\show\SI`; the output is

```
> \SI=\protected macro:
->\int_zero:N \l__xparse_processor_int \tl_set:Nn \l__xparse_args_tl {\SI code }\tl_set:Nn \l__xparse_fn_tl {\SI  }\__xparse_grab_D:w []{-NoValue-}\__xparse_grab_m_1:w \__xparse_grab_D:w []{-NoValue-}\__xparse_grab_m_1:w \l__xparse_args_tl .
```

the usefulness of which is very dubious.

Another example. Suppose you're using `amsmath` and want to access the definition of `\bar`; a `\show` command would print

```
> \bar=macro:
->\protect \mathaccentV {bar}016.
```

but you'll *never* find where this definition is performed, because there's no `\def`, `\newcommand` or any other similar command that does it: indeed in `amsmath.sty` you find (line numbers for convenience)

```
574 \def\set@mathaccent#1#2#3#4{%
575   \xdef#2{\@nx\protect\@nx\mathaccentV
576     {\@xp\@gobble\string#2}\hexnumber@#1#4}%
577 }
578 \def\@tempa#1{\@xp\@tempb\meaning#1\@nil#1}
579 \def\@tempb#1>#2#3 #4\@nil#5{%
580   \@xp\ifx\csname#3\endcsname\mathaccent
581     \@tempc#4?"7777\@nil#5%
582   \else
583     \PackageWarningNoLine{amsmath}{%
584       Unable to redefine math accent \string#5}%
585   \fi
586 }
587 \def\@tempc#1"#2#3#4#5#6\@nil#7{%
588   \chardef\@tempd="#3\relax\set@mathaccent\@tempd{#7}{#2}{#4#5}}
589 \@tempa{\hat}
590 \@tempa{\check}
591 \@tempa{\tilde}
592 \@tempa{\acute}
593 \@tempa{\grave}
594 \@tempa{\dot}
595 \@tempa{\ddot}
596 \@tempa{\breve}
597 \@tempa{\bar}
598 \@tempa{\vec}
```

and it's line 597 that performs the redefinition from the kernel's meaning

```
\mathaccent "7016\relax
```

that's assigned in `fontmath.ltx` by the high level instruction

```
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"16}
```

Final example. You can't even guess the syntax of a command from its definition: here's the output of `\show\makebox`

```
> \makebox=macro:
->\leavevmode \@ifnextchar (\@makepicbox {\@ifnextchar [\@makebox \mbox }.
```

Comment: Nice answer, but isn't this true for many languages? In Python I can `eval()` a string containing a function definition, or reassign a function name; in Lisp I can rebind symbols; etc.  And yet for all of these languages there are good solutions that work most of the time.  Do you think LaTeX would be significantly worse? (the existence of texdef and latexdef gives me some hope). One could start by just looking for \def, \newcommand, \DeclareRobustCommand, etc. lines and show the match if a match pops up.

Comment: @Clément My example shows that looking for `\def` or similar strings is not sufficient.

Comment: Of course; just like search for `(defun` in elisp isn't sufficient, but doesn't it get you some of the way? Or maybe your intuition is that it's much more common in TeX and LaTeX to have a command that doesn't match a simple pattern?

Comment: @Clément Indeed, most commands are defined with `\def` or variants. But some of the important ones aren't. You don't find `\alpha` this way.

Answer (score 5):

I'll mention TeXlipse, [which includes this feature](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/editormisc.html#declaration), though only partially. You can press F3 when the cursor is on a macro name, to jump to its definition. But...

- TeXlipse does not take redefinitions via `\renewcommand` into account.
- It does not understand macros defined by `\def`. Only `\newcommand` seems to work.

Nevertheless...

- It *does* work if the macro is defined outside of the current file, in a package that you include via `\usepackage`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a regex (PCRE) similar to `/(\\def|\\renewcommand|\\newkeycommand).*$cmdname/`.

Hope this helps, I can't write any lisp for it right now, but it should be trivial to implement.