# Which TeX editors can jump to \import source directly?

Tags: editors, import, source

Which of the TeX editors have the possibility to make jump by clicking to source file `some_source_tex_file.tex` in `\import{some-dir}{some_source_tex_file.tex}` in view for editing?

---

Bigest thank you for answers!

Tell me, if **\import** or **\subimport** have the dir part as \newcommand element - this construction is possible for click and jump to view **some_file.tex**?

`\newcommand{\commonPath}{../../../common} 
\subimport{\commonPath/somedir/}{some_file.tex}`

Comment: Not by clicking, but Vim has a command for that, see `help gf`.

Comment: With some lines of code in Elisp, [Emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113376/31416).

Answer (score 6):

In `texstudio` you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `Left click` to open the file directly(*) or `right click` and then `open <your-file-name>.tex`.

[image]

Or from within the pdf `right click` and `Go to Source` will also open the file `<your-file-name>.tex` (if `synctex` is activated).

[image]

(*) Thanks to Troy for [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379833/which-the-tex-editor-can-jump-to-import/379870?noredirect=1#comment940302_379870)!

Comment: Ctrl + Left clicking on the `file.tex` in the `\import` command will work as well (in TeXstudio).

Comment: @Troy Thanks for your comment! I added this information to the answer!