# Is there a reason for \usepackage with options in a separate line?

Tags: geometry, syntax, package-options

I understand that these two commands do the same thing:

```
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=2in]{geometry}
```

and

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=2in}
```

Is there any reason why one would be preferable over the other? I mean to ask this question not just with reference to the geometry package, but in general if possible.

Comment: If a class you're using already loads `geometry` the second way is mandatory, otherwise there's no difference.

Comment: Sometimes people load multiple packages in one call, e.g. `\usepackage{geometry, fancyhdr}`; in this case, the second way would also be mandatory.

Comment: Please post that as an answer. Both really.  And thank you, this was driving me nuts not knowing.

Comment: Possible also cover that the kernel expands stuff (not important here but is for other packages).

Comment: Sometimes it matters. Some packages are such that certain options can only be given in particular ways e.g. at load time `\usepackage[<option>]{<package>}` or they don't provide an equivalent of `\geometry{}`. Also, in some cases, you might want to set certain options after `\begin{document}` when you can no longer use `\usepackage`. (Other times, options can only be set in the preamble, of course.) I guess: 'It depends. Oh, and it is complicated.' is probably closest to the truth.

Comment: Related: [Loading Packages Together versus Separately](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104338/17423)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible for some packages, but not necessarily *all* options can be set in either way.

Notable packages that allow for separate commands are

- `geometry` and `\geometry`
- `hyperref` and `\hypersetup`
- `microtype` and `\microtypesetup`
- `siunitx` and `\sisetup`
- `caption` and `captionsetup`

(the list is not exhaustive).

There are some differences; `\geometry` can only be given in the preamble, whereas the setup commands for the other packages can go essentially anywhere and respect grouping.

Consult the documentation for each package to see what options (maybe none) doesn't make sense in `\usepackage` or in the setup command.

Some peculiarity: if you want different settings for figure and table captions, you *must* use `\captionsetup`. For `caption` I actually would recommend using the command form anyway, rather than a long list of package options.

There is another relevant aspect. Suppose you want to set the text width using a macro that you want to set in a separate place, maybe for doing experiments. An input such as

```
\usepackage[textwidth=\mytextwidth]{geometry}

\newcommand{\mytextwidth}{13cm}

\begin{document}
```

wouldn't work even if we know that `geometry` does its settings at begin document, because the optional argument to `\usepackage` is fully expanded at calling time. To the contrary,

```
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{textwidth=\mytextwidth}

\newcommand{\mytextwidth}{13cm}

\begin{document}
```

would work, because options in that case are not fully expanded at calling time but only when the setting is actually performed

<sup>Such behavior will probably change in LaTeX3, which will use newer option processing functions also in `\documentclass` and `\usepackage`).</sup>

So what method you use is mostly a personal choice. However there are cases where the command way is *mandatory*. If the document class you use already loads, say, `geometry`, you can't call `\usepackage[<options>]{geometry}` with a different set of options; the command form is free of this problem . The same for the other packages, but note that some options to `hyperref` cannot be undone with `\hypersetup` once they have been set in the package options.